# Get how many user viewed notification laravel API for android app

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to get how many people or users viewed the notification,when the user click on notification it will open to profile page of user,so how do i get how many user viewed the notification i am kind lost touch with laravel,so help is appreciated

Table
[image]

```
public function notifcationCount(Request $request){
    $input = $request->all();
    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'notifcationcount' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());
    }
     $notifcationCount=$request->notifcationcount;
     $notification = NotificationCount::where('notification_view_count', $notifcationCount)->first();
     $notification->notification_view_count = $notification->notification_view_count+1;
    $notification->save();
    if(!empty($notification)){
        $success['status'] = 200;
         return $this->sendResponse($success, 'notificationcount increased');
    }
    else
    {
        $success['status'] = 201;
         return $this->sendResponse($success, 'notificationcount increase failed');
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take field in table notification_view_count when the user will click on notification then hit api to increment the notification_view_count by 1.
Replace NotificationModel with your notification model name,

Create function like this:

```
public function updateNotificationCount($notification_id)
{
    $notification = NotificationModel::where('id', $id)->first();
    $notification->notification_view_count = $notification->notification_view_count+1;
    $notification->save()
}
```

Make new route for this action and hit that route from android app

Comment: Can you look into what i did,i have updated question  also it throws error `"Trying to get property 'notification_view_count' of non-object"` @Ranjeet

Comment: you have to add new field in table "notification_view_count" @Morbius

Comment: i have already did this added id,notification_view_count  in table @Ranjeet

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have solved with increment,but thanks for the idea by @Ranjeet

```
 public function notifcationCount(Request $request){
        $input = $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'notifcationcount' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());
        }
         $notifcationCount=$request->notifcationcount;
        $notification = DB::table('notificationcount')->increment('notification_view_count',$notifcationCount);
        $getCount = DB::table('notificationcount')->select('notification_view_count')->first();

        if(!empty($getCount)){
             $success['status'] = 200;
             $success['Count'] = $getCount;
             return $this->sendResponse($success, 'Notification Count increased');
        }
        else
        {
            $success['status'] = 201;
             return $this->sendResponse($success, 'Notification Count increase failed');
        }
    }
```